# How to execute large MySql data-insert script file?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Trying to use PHPMyAdmin doesn't allow me to execute 150Mb data script file. Do you have any work-around for me?

*Update*

My script is **utf-8** encode.

I've update `php.ini` but all still get error as the below snapshot.

[php.ini]

```
upload_max_filesize = 256M    
max_execution_time = 0    
memory_limit = 256M
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:  http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/

Bigdump  also provides you changing character set

Answer (score 1):

Use split on linux or a windows split program to split your script in multiple parts. And then load them one by one.

Comment: How much should I split then? It's quite annoying in splitting it though.

Comment: Depends on many factors, do some trial and error on how much inserts you can do in PhpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

Give `max_execution_time = 1500` (Which means 25 minuets)

Default execution time is 30sec, http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php

Comment: I set it to be 0 already i.e. infinite but that doesn't work. 25 minutes won't be enough though

Answer (score 1):

Use native mysql console client. To import that file use

```
mysql -u [username] -p[password] [database_name] < [your_sql_file]
```

Comment: This won't help me to import utf-8 data

Comment: Hic... How can I prove it to you then

Comment: @Nam Gi VU Hm.. I think you can't because I use this method enough often to claim that it works :)

Comment: This is my sample script in utf8 http://db.tt/IyNbFAj. Have tried successful using `Navicat execute sql file` but running from commandline failed

Comment: @Nam Gi VU Oh.. that's simple problem with your SQL query :) Just add `SET NAMES utf8;` in the beginning of file.

Comment: @Nam Gi VU Alternatively, you may use cmd-line parameter `--default_character_set=utf8` when running this import.